# Automapper: map from non-polymorphic list to polymorphic list

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

My models:

```
class SourceViewModel
{
    bool IsCpmplex {get;set;}
    String SimpleProp {get;set;}
    String ComplexProp {get;set;}
}
class TargetSimpleModel
{
    String SimpleProp {get;set;}
}
class TargetComplexModel : TargetSimpleModel
{
    String ComplexProp {get;set;}
}
```

I want to map `List<SourceViewModel>` to `List<TargetSimpleModel>` with inheritance in target list. Inheritance is based on source peoperty IsCopmplex (it should be used as discriminator).

**Result example.**

If source list is like this:

```
{
    SourceViewModel{IsComplex=true,...},
    SourceViewModel{IsComplex=false,...}
}
```

Dest list should be:

```
{
    TargetComplexModel, // with all props mapped 
    TargetSimpleModel
}
```

My current confg (doesn`t work correctly):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceViewModel, TargetSimpleModel>()
    .ConstructUsing(model => model.IsComplex ? new TargetComplexModel() : new TargetSimpleModel())
    .Include<SourceViewModel, TargetComplexModel>()
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceViewModel, TargetComplexModel>();
```

It works, but doesn`t map properties of TargetComplexModel (like ComplexProp). 
I need a way to make automapper use spacific map for derived type when ConstructUsing returns it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I`m currently using a dirty solution with AfterMap and if(isComplex) {call Mapper.Map;}

Comment: you can use `ValueResolver` or `TypeConverter`s